# Material UI inputs are small

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles

**Hi I am using material ui in react and in normal size my inputs are smaller** than select it should'nt be like that - https://prnt.sc/v97xtd

I am writing everything like it was in documentation , please help me

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default function InputKey() {
    return (
        <>
        <TextField
          required
          id="sth"
          label="Keywords"
          defaultValue=""
          variant="filled"
        />
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
size="medium"
```

```
<TextField
  required
  id="sth"
  label="Keywords"
  defaultValue=""
  variant="filled"
  size="medium"// add
/>
```

see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/o8c7v)

Comment: I have tryed it too